# How to write a for loop to create multiple new variables in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

Suppose I have this example dataset df with only character variables.

```
dx_order1<-c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1)
dx_order2<-c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA)
```

Suppose that these variables are numeric.

I want to recode the variables. For dx_order1 variable, I want to recode 1 as 1 and 0 otherwise. Similarly, for dx_order 2 variable I want to recode 2 as 1 and 0 otherwise. Say that the new variables are called diag_order1 and diag_order2.

I know how to do this one by one in a manual fashion. The codes below will do the job:

```
df$diag_order1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$dx_order1), 0, 1)
df$diag_order1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$dx_order1), 0, 1)
```

I was wondering how I can achieve the same outcome with for loop function. If I have a a lot of similar variables then this type of manual coding is not practical. So any advice on how to have a loop to fasten the process would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `loop` in this instance, you could do this by converting `NA` to 0 using `is.na`. For example:

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(dx_order1 = c(1,1, NA, 1, 1),
                 dx_order2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA))

df[!is.na(df)] <- 1
df[is.na(df)] <- 0
```

Or if you have more columns with `NA` but only want to apply to certain columns then you could do it by specifying those columns:

```
df2 <- data.frame(letter_col = c(NA, letters[1:4]), 
                 dx_order1 = c(1,1, NA, 1, 1),
                 dx_order2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA))

# any columns starting with dx
cols <- names(df2)[grepl("^dx", names(df2))]

df2[, cols][!is.na(df2[, cols])] <- 1
df2[, cols][is.na(df2[, cols])] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `across` with `mutate` in `dplyr` like this

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- data.frame(letter_col = c(NA, letters[1:4]), 
                  dx_order1 = c(1,1, NA, 1, 1),
                  dx_order2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA))
> df2
  letter_col dx_order1 dx_order2
1       <NA>         1         2
2          a         1         2
3          b        NA         2
4          c         1         2
5          d         1        NA

df2 %>% mutate(across(starts_with("dx"), ~case_when(. == as.numeric(str_extract(cur_column(), "\\d$")) ~ 1,
                                                    is.na(.) ~ 0,
                                                    TRUE ~ 0), .names = "diag_{.col}"))

  letter_col dx_order1 dx_order2 diag_dx_order1 diag_dx_order2
1       <NA>         1         2              1              1
2          a         1         2              1              1
3          b        NA         2              0              1
4          c         1         2              1              1
5          d         1        NA              1              0
```

**Assuming that your `dx` column can have values like suffix, NA and otherwise too as written in your question, and it recodes everything else than suffix to 0**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if these codes are applicable to large datasets. Suppose I have 100 variables that require this type of transformation, isn't it better to use a loop function instead?

Comment: You can very well use across for large datasets and these functions may rather be faster than loops.

Answer (score 1):

You can coerce the logical vector from `is.na` to integer. `is.na` works with the dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(dx_order1 = c(1,1, NA, 1, 1),
                 dx_order2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, NA))

df[] <- +!is.na(df)
df

#  dx_order1 dx_order2
#1         1         1
#2         1         1
#3         0         1
#4         1         1
#5         1         0
```